# change a string in a function passing a pointer

Tags: c

Hello I have some trouble with pointer !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(char **str)
{
    *str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
    *str[0] = 'b';
    *str[1] = '\0';
}

int     main(void)
{
    char *str;

    test(&str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return (0);
}
```

So I pass a pointer of an non allocated string in my function test, then I allocate my string in the function and try to manipulate it but this code segfault so I guess I miss something on my pointer lesson :)

Can you help me to figure out what is happening here ? thank you a lot !

edit : when I remove my return (0) in the main, the code compile and display my char * ! super weird

Comment: To avoid array indexing try using this (**str = 'b'; *(*str+1) = '\0';) in your code

Comment: Maybe you were taught otherwise, but [don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Also, checking the return value is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must write:

```
(*str)[0]= 'b';
```

You must first dereference the `str` and now the indexing will work on the target, the memory allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: thank you ! It's working fine. can you explain to me how *str[0] is interpreted ? because *str[] and (*str)[] seems pretty similar to me

Comment: @hadewsMM *str[0] means `*(str[0])`

Answer (score 3):

The array subscript operator `[]` has higher precedence than the indirection operator `*`.  So the assignment to `str` is effectively this which is incorrect:

```
*(str[0]) = 'b';
*(str[1]) = '\0';
```

You need to add parenthesis:

```
(*str)[0] = 'b';
(*str)[1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just 'str' itself means he address of character array. 
But 'str' means the value of str. 
So the str[0] contains the value of 'b' but as you added '' before str[0] (*str[0]), computer trying to find the value where the address is 'b'.
But this address is not allowed for this process. So this program returns segment fault. Thank you.